How to correctly create a String which, After Deserialization can be used to fetch Properties of a Dynamic Object via index
I have a method that desterilizes a string to a Dynamic object, and then accesses it's properties via Index. This is a Customer written code that can not be changed.
public void CustomerMethod(string Content)
{
    dynamic jsonData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(Content);
    string myvalue1 = jsonData["myvalue1"];
    string myvalue2 = jsonData["myvalue2"];
}

I am trying to call this method from my code MyMethod. I am allowed to modify my method. I am trying to populate a String which can be deserialized by the customer method. I have tried this.
public void MyMethod()
{
    string Json = @"{
        ""myvalue1"": ""Somevalue1"",
        ""myvalue2"": ""Somevalue2""    
    }";
    CustomerMethod(Json);
}

In Customer method, the deserialization works, but the jsonData["myvalue1"] fails with this error
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'The best overloaded method match 
for 'System.Text.Json.JsonElement.this[int]' has some invalid arguments'

What could be the issue? How to modify my code so that the CustomerMethod works ?

You can't. The System.Text.Json serializer will deserialize it into a JsonElement. According to the documentation the JsonElement class has no string indexer (this[string]) method. So the code is faulty and won't work no matter the input.
If you really can't change the code there's little you can do. But to give advice to others coming to this thread you can navigate and read the property using the following:
jsonData.GetProperty("myvalue1").GetString();

